# How to uninstall dell support assist with powershell?

Tags: powershell

So there was an article that came out about support assist being vulnerable, bla bla.

Upper management has deemed support assist to be unsafe and has ordered it removed from every machine.....

no I cannot/will not try to convince them otherwise, this is going to happen one way or another

Trying to get this done has been a nightmare for the past 8 hours while I try unsuccessful script after the next only to have this damned program NOT DIE

Here is what I have so far

```
MsiExec.exe /X "{0309AC01-330F-494C-B27D-58E297E4674F}" /quiet
MsiExec.exe /X "{F1D17890-F41B-4BFA-8893-B2C8A248BE0D}" /quiet

$CurrentSAPkg = Get-WMIObject -Class Win32_Product  | Where-Object { $_.Name -like "Dell*" }
$CurrentSAPkg.Uninstall()

& "C:\Program Files\Dell\SupportAssist\uninstaller.exe" /arp /S
```

The get-WMIObject part works, and the uninstaller.exe /arp /S works

however those only work for the older versions, newer versions require something more like the top two commands, but there is a problem

the /quiet flag makes it not work. if I omit the quiet flag I get a popup, "Are you sure" yes, it uninstalls, with the quiet flag, nothing happens, the program stays

I use the folowing to get the uninstall paths

```
$regQuery32 = Get-ChildItem -Path "HKLM:\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall" | Where {$_.GetValue("DisplayName") -match "Dell*"}
```

I really hate support assist now and I want it to die and I am at my wits end.

Comment: `msiexec /?` is your friend

Answer (score 2):

So I am having the exact opposite issue. I was able to get the newer versions to remove, but anything that returned "C:\Program Files\Dell\SupportAssist\uninstaller.exe /arp" as the UninstallString is failing in my automation as I can't get the prompt to not display (I have around 700 agents to remove this crap from, some with multiple versions, so I feel your pain).

For the newer versions, I used:

```
$SAVer = Get-ChildItem -Path HKLM:\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall, HKLM:\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall  |
    Get-ItemProperty |
        Where-Object {$_.DisplayName -match "SupportAssist" } |
        Where-Object {$_.DisplayVersion -notlike "3.2*"} | 
            Select-Object -Property DisplayVersion, UninstallString, PSChildName

ForEach ($ver in $SAVer) {

    If ($ver.UninstallString) {

        $uninst = $ver.UninstallString
        & cmd /c $uninst /quiet /norestart

    }
}
```

I am going to look into the method you are showing for the older version (2.0 and earlier) to see if this resolves my issue. Hopefully my code snippet will help with yours. Cheers.

Comment: Worked perfectly for me. I left out the version part just for brevity. Also, I ran that script on one machine to make sure it works as intended and figured out the PSChildName was the same across the board so I just used a static version of the `cmd` part of the script to run on all of the workstations. For anyone curious, on version 3.3.3.13, the only batch command you would have to run is `MsiExec.exe /X{95BD6E30-2B18-4FB0-B5AE-8250E5584831} /quiet /norestart`

Answer (score 2):

Ran into a similar problem. I had a bunch of computers all with different versions of Support Assist. I compiled this from a few different sources. So far I have had really good success. I am using PDQ deploy. I am not the most PowerShell proficient but perhaps this will help.

```
"C:\ProgramData\Package Cache\{ec40a028-983b-4213-af2c-77ed6f6fe1d5}\DellUpdateSupportAssistPlugin.exe" /uninstall /quiet
MsiExec.exe /qn /norestart /X{E98E94E2-12D1-48E5-AC69-2C312F466136}
MsiExec.exe /qn /norestart /X{806422F1-FC4E-4D7C-8855-05748AEFC031}
MsiExec.exe /X{0309AC01-330F-494C-B27D-58E297E4674F} /qn REBOOT=REALLYSUPRESS
MsiExec.exe /X{122666A9-2995-4E47-A75E-6423A827B7AF} /qn REBOOT=REALLYSUPRESS
MsiExec.exe /X{18EF001B-B005-46CB-917B-112BA69ED85E} /qn REBOOT=REALLYSUPRESS
MsiExec.exe /X{1AE53ECE-2255-4191-998B-07741E5EFCDA} /qn REBOOT=REALLYSUPRESS
MsiExec.exe /X{33E712C1-2183-421C-9BC8-C902DB9C596C} /qn REBOOT=REALLYSUPRESS
MsiExec.exe /X{45FD01F4-B11B-4A58-B465-1D600B5CDF64} /qn REBOOT=REALLYSUPRESS
MsiExec.exe /X{4CB4741A-20C1-454E-8276-993D06A76D67} /qn REBOOT=REALLYSUPRESS
MsiExec.exe /X{50EF2C72-95EC-4206-AAC3-9E84004A6140} /qn REBOOT=REALLYSUPRESS
MsiExec.exe /X{5A18ABE3-52D1-4CA5-9169-25EC7E789582} /qn REBOOT=REALLYSUPRESS
MsiExec.exe /X{8D7B279C-A661-465C-9658-F62FBD6A6B91} /qn REBOOT=REALLYSUPRESS
MsiExec.exe /X{9074E264-F615-4DDE-969E-1FDBCFEC3FB5} /qn REBOOT=REALLYSUPRESS
MsiExec.exe /X{90881C8E-6C4F-4662-9923-85AFCA058C44} /qn REBOOT=REALLYSUPRESS
MsiExec.exe /X{9DD6B149-CEBC-4910-B11A-242393EDF6D3} /qn REBOOT=REALLYSUPRESS
MsiExec.exe /X{D793D5B1-A985-4443-90F4-E55A13CFF117} /qn REBOOT=REALLYSUPRESS
MsiExec.exe /X{E98E94E2-12D1-48E5-AC69-2C312F466136} /qn REBOOT=REALLYSUPRESS
MsiExec.exe /X{806422F1-FC4E-4D7C-8855-05748AEFC031} /qn REBOOT=REALLYSUPRESS
MsiExec.exe /X{27130E51-9555-408B-8134-7BFF54EDE27B} /qn REBOOT=REALLYSUPRESS
MsiExec.exe /X{3ED468C2-2235-4747-90AD-A7A34F0FE70A} /qn REBOOT=REALLYSUPRESS
taskkill /im SupportAssistAgent.exe /f /t
net stop SupportAssistAgent
sc delete SupportAssistAgent
rd "C:\Program Files\Dell\SupportAssist"/s /q
rd "C:\Program Files\Dell\SupportAssistAgent" /s /q
reg delete "HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall\PC-Doctor for Windows" /f
del "C:\Users\Public\Desktop\SupportAssist.lnk" /f /q
```

Sources:
https://community.spiceworks.com/topic/2229972-using-pdq-deploy-to-uninstall-dell-supportassist
https://www.dell.com/community/SupportAssist-for-PCs/Silently-Update-SupportAssist-in-background/td-p/7294483

Comment: Though using soon-to-be legacy command line utilities, this will run just fine in PowerShell.  Copy, paste, save with .ps1 extension...done.  Old question but useful answer :)

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried something like:

```
get-package *dell* | uninstall-package -whatif
```

Answer (score 0):

I know this is an old post but I was just looking for a script to do this and ended up writing my own Powershell script.

This is what I came up with..
Uninstalls "Dell SupportAssist" and "Dell SupportAssist OS Recovery Plugin for Dell Update"
Hope this helps someone else too.. The code probably could be cleaned up or simplified a bit but it worked for me.

---

```
$supportassist = Get-ChildItem -Path HKLM:\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall| Get-ItemProperty | Where-Object {$_.DisplayName -ceq "Dell SupportAssist" } | Select-Object -ExpandProperty UninstallString
if ($supportassist)
{
    $arguments = $supportassist.substring(12) + " /qn REBOOT=REALLYSUPRESS"
    echo "Uninstalling Dell SupportAsist"
    echo "msiexec.exe " $arguments
    (Start-Process "msiexec.exe" -ArgumentList $arguments -NoNewWindow -Wait -PassThru).ExitCode
}

$supportassist2 = Get-ChildItem -Path HKLM:\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall| Get-ItemProperty | Where-Object {$_.DisplayName -ceq "Dell SupportAssist OS Recovery Plugin for Dell Update" } | Select-Object -ExpandProperty UninstallString
if ($supportassist2)
{
    $arguments2 = $supportassist2.substring(12) + " /qn"
    echo "Uninstalling Dell SupportAssist OS Recovery Plugin for Dell Update"
    echo "msiexec.exe " $arguments2
    (Start-Process "msiexec.exe" -ArgumentList $arguments2 -NoNewWindow -Wait -PassThru).ExitCode
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a Powershell script that I currently use to remove it

```
Param (
    [Parameter(Mandatory=$false)]
    [switch]$Force = $false,
    [Parameter(Mandatory=$false)]
    [String] $SoftwareVersion = "3.11"
)

$Software = "Dell SupportAssist"
$ScriptName = $myinvocation.MyCommand
Function Remove-CachedScripts {


    $Agent = "C:\Program Files\N-able Technologies\Windows Agent"

    if (test-path "C:\Program Files (x86)\N-able Technologies\Windows Agent") {
        $Agent = "C:\Program Files (x86)\N-able Technologies\Windows Agent"
    }
    remove-item "$Agent\cache\$scriptname" -force -erroraction SilentlyContinue
    remove-item "$Agent\Temp\Script\$scriptname"  -force -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue
}
Function Get-InstalledApp($Target) {
    $Apps = @()
    
    $Apps += Get-ChildItem -Path HKLM:\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall  |
           Get-ItemProperty | Where-Object {$_.DisplayName -eq "$Target" } | Select-Object -Property DisplayName, DisplayVersion, UninstallString
           
                
    If ($(Get-WmiObject Win32_OperatingSystem).OSArchitecture -match "64") {
        $Apps += Get-ChildItem -Path HKLM:\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall  |
           Get-ItemProperty | Where-Object {$_.DisplayName -eq "$Target" } | Select-Object -Property DisplayName, DisplayVersion, UninstallString
        }
        
    $Apps
}

Function Uninstall-Software {

    if ($SoftwareUninstall -ne $null) {
       
        if (($($SoftwareUninstall.DisplayVersion) -ge "$SoftwareVersion") -and ($force -eq $false)) {

            exit 0
        }


        if ($($SoftwareUninstall.DisplayVersion) -lt "$SoftwareVersion") {

            }
                    ForEach ($item in $SoftwareUninstall) {
                        if (($item.displayversion -le "$softwareversion") -or ($force -eq $true)) {
                        

                        If ($item.UninstallString) {
                        
                            $uninst = $item.UninstallString.Split('/X')[0]
                            $guid = $item.UninstallString.Split('/X')[2] 
                            $argument = "/x $guid /qn /norestart"
                            
                            
                            Start-Process $uninst -ArgumentList "$argument" -wait -passthru -NoNewWindow
                            
                            $Timeout = 0
                            $MaxWait = 10 
                            
                            While (($CheckSoftware -ne $null) -and ($Timeout -lt $MaxWait)) { 
                                Start-Sleep -Seconds 30
                                $Timeout++
                                
                                $CheckSoftware = Get-InstalledApp("$Software")
                            }

                            If ($CheckSoftware -eq $null) 
                                {
                                        Exit 0
                                } 
                    }
                }
            }
        } 
}

 
$SoftwareUninstall = . Get-InstalledApp($software)
. Uninstall-Software
Remove-CachedScripts
```